# Prove that if $v$ is orthogonal to $u$, then it is orthogonal to any scalar multiple of $u$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

I never understand where to start with proofs, but whenever I see them done I understand them.

My attempt:

For this one could I just use the property of inner products to prove this?

That being $v\cdot (cu)=c(u\cdot v)$, for $c$ a scalar and $u,v$ vectors. And if so then how would I prove it? Just write that by the property of inner products if $v$ is orthogonal to $u$ then it is orthogonal to any scalar multiple of $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbf{v}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{u}$, then $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{u}=0$. So by the property you mentioned we get
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{v} \cdot c\mathbf{u} & = c (\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{u})\\
& = c (0)\\
& = 0.
\end{align*}
Thus $\mathbf{v}$ is orthogonal to $c\,\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: Made perfect sense, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well yes. As long as your product does have this property, then you're good to go.

Let u and v be elements of whatever space you're working on, and c a scalar.

Suppose v is orthogonal to u.

Then u⋅v = 0.

Let us calculate (c.u)⋅v. By property of ⋅, (c.u)⋅v = c x (u⋅v) = c x 0 = 0 (where x designates the product between scalars). Thus v is orthogonal to c.u .

The latter is true for any scalar c - QED.